# Resume Fragments in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, resume

I am currently working on sample android navigation drawer application. It contains 1 activity and four fragments (import android.app.Fragment). I do not know how to resume the previous fragments, for example now I am in Fragment A here I did some activities like selected checkbox some thing like this. then I have moved to Fragment B, now if I press back button I want to resume the Fragment A with the previous state (with selected check box). please provide some sample code.

thanks in advance

Comment: with shared preferences maybe?

Comment: with shared preferences how is possible?

Comment: onResume() of your fragment just setChecked of your selection checkbox id that stored in sharedPreferences

Comment: no no, actually that is not the issue just for example i said that. my basic need is i need to resume like activity

Comment: just do something in your onResume() fragment. i cant give you sample code. do it yourself and if you troubled by something then ask here

Comment: for example i did some things in Activity A then i called Activity B. if i finish or pressed activity B, we will get the Activity A with the previous state instead of new instance. like this I need to do in fragments.. can u get my query?

Answer (score 0):

As described in the documentation (http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html#back-fragments) you can add the fragment to the back stack:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                       .add(detailFragment, "detail")
                       // Add this transaction to the back stack
                       .addToBackStack()
                       .commit();
```

Comment: I can not use getSupportFragmentManager(), instead of that I am using getFragmentManager() is it cause any isuues. if not then please explain how to get the fragment from backstack, I have added the fragment to backstack but struggling to get from backstack

Comment: Using getFragmentManager is fine, it just means you're not using the support library so your stuff isn't backwards compatible. You shouldn't get it from the backstack when you use the back button it pulls from the top of the back stack which should include your fragment.